# Sending google-analytics pageview is not logged - as active user

Tags: google-analytics

When I send the request from fiddler or from .net code - I see the counter in Analytics active users
But when it is sent from a cloud machine - I get 200 OK but the counter does not change

Possible problems:

1. response is from cache
2. Results are filtered by region (I couldn't find any active filter)
3. Needed header

Request format: [https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?t=pageview&v=1&dp={myDp}&tid={myTid}&cid={myCid}](https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?t=pageview&v=1&dp=%7BmyDp%7D&tid=%7BmyTid%7D&cid=%7BmyCid%7D)

The request was built based on this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference

Any more ideas?

Dekel

Comment: how exactly are you sending this from your cloud machine?

Comment: From a java application using the apache client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you are looking at a view where `Bot Filtering` is enabled:

[image]

It happens because your call has few parameters (for example it doesn't have the parameter of screen resolution, host name, etc...) therefore it is interpreted as a bot.

Try to see the data in a View where there is no filter (or disable this option) or to enrich the call with more parameters.